# Spring startup listener which works in junit

Tags: spring, unit-testing, application-lifecycle

Hi i have an web application unsing spring and hibernate.
I'm looking for a possiblity to call some startup functions which are executed when running tests, too.

I uste the AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests class and tried the following interfaces

- ApplicationListener
- Lifecycle
- ServletContextListener

but none of them is called under junit.

Any tips (hibernate-database-acces should be available at this time)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution: ApplicationContextAware, just add a class to your classpath:

```
public class SpringApplicationContext implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private static ApplicationContext CONTEXT;

    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext context) throws BeansException {
        CONTEXT = context;
        // DO DB INIT STUFF
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Annotation ContextConfiguration to load the application Context for your Tests.

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations="test/test-context.xml")
public class MyTestsClass {
    // class body...
}
```

Regards 
Michael

Comment: i already have this, but none of the triggers above is called